# How to pick a document in android 13

Tags: android, android-permissions, read-write, filepicker, android-13

I have tried picking documents and applied check that if file exist or not it always return false.
It means I can't read file I have tried doing this with SAF `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`

I can get URI and getting path from uri as `fileUri.path` then i got error that file or directory don't exist also I have tried to get file path with other way PathUtils class but it always return null.

What I am missing or is there any other way to read documents without having all files access permission.

Comment: `fileUri.path` That is no file system path. Those directories -that path-  do not exist. Look at the value.

Comment: uri.path is from kotlin and it is equal to uri.getPath() it is mentioned that it will return the path of file.

Comment: Well tell which 'path' you got. It is no path to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT gives you an uri.

You can open an inputstream for this uri using getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri).

Then read from the stream.

And you do not need any permission to do so.

And this works from Android 4 KitKat to today.